# What is the best way to get nested relationships in Laravel Nova?

Tags: laravel, laravel-nova

I have 3 tables with relationships; Feedback has one Type and a Type has multiple Answers:

Feedback->Type->Answers

In Nova, I want to display all Answers to the currently Type on the Feedback page. What is the best way to achieve this? Using using Pivot Fields?

Nova/Feedback:

```
HasOne::make('Type', 'answer', Type::class),
shows error: call to undefined urikey. my models also match nova relationships
```

Nova/Type:

```
HasMany::make('Answer'),
```

Nova/Answer:

```
BelongsTo::make('Type'),
```

Answer (score 0):

Is it only to display or also to add while creating a model?

What we mostly use is this packages:
https://novapackages.com/packages/yassi/nova-nested-form

and we extend where needed in specific usecases.